# CSS attribute start with caret

Tags: html, css

Many of the CSS attributes in the project I'm currently maintaining start with a caret `^` like so:

```
<tr style="^padding-bottom: 10px;">
```

Does the caret have any meaning? Perhaps a fix for some obscure browser? Or is it just a typo from a previous developer that has been copy-pasted x times (as it is always there together with the 'padding-bottom')?

Comment: Interesting; that's not a CSS character I've come across before (except for the newer attribute-starts-with selectors).

Comment: Looks like a mistake, I have never seen that before, and can't find any source on ´^´ to be a browser fix.

Comment: My gut reaction would be some misguided attempt at a browser hack, but I also can't find any reference to that being used in the past. I'm voting typo/mistake.

Comment: @DA. "Many of the CSS" - many identical typos?

Comment: @Christoph sure. If it was cut-and-pasted or simply generated programatically, it could litter everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The styles with the caret in front of them don't get applied. So it might be a way  to **comment out** CSS styles in this case, without having to use entire HTML comments. It isn't a standard way to do it though.

**[(Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/fKygP/1/)**

---

The caret character in CSS does have meaning, the "Begins With" [**Attribute selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

It lets you target an element in your CSS based on whether the attribute’s value begins with a given string.

```
E[foo]  an E element with a "foo" attribute
E[foo="bar"]    an E element whose "foo" attribute value is exactly equal to "bar"
E[foo~="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar"
E[foo^="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"
E[foo$="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar"
E[foo*="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar"
```

However, in your case, the caret **isn't functioning** as a selector.

Comment: This is inline, it is not a selector.

Comment: I was explaining what caret is in CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the caret has meaning in CSS 3, It is an [**attribute selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) in CSS 3. This Selector allow the representation of an element's attribute. When a selector is used as an expression to match against an element, [**attribute selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) must be considered to match an element if that element has an attribute that matches the attribute represented by the [**attribute selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

**But in your case it might be a typo.**

**[CSS3 Attribute Selectors - Substring Matching](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-attribute-selectors-substring-matching/)**

Three of the attribute selectors in the CSS3 spec allow you to check the value the specified attribute for a string match. These attribute selectors are referred to as [**substring matching attribute selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).

**[att^=val]**

> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

**[att$=val]**

> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

**[att*=val]**

> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.